# Below bound of the mesure of a finite intersection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, inequality

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, with $\mu(X)=1$. If $A_{1}, A_{2}, ..., A_{n} \in \mathcal{M}$, prove that $$\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} A_{j} \right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mu{(A_{j})} - (n-1).$$
I tried to write X as disjoint unions of sets so that the sum of their measure is 1 and then use subadditivity, but it does not seem to work...

Comment: Hint: use induction. (You have to deal with $n=2$ case first to do the induction. That's where you need to use $\mu(X)=1$.)

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting this in terms of $X\setminus A_j$ and using $\mu(X)=1$, the inequality is equivalent to 
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n(X\setminus A_j)\right)\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n\mu(X\setminus A_j).$$
This can be handled integrating the inequality 
$$\chi\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^nB_j\right)\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n\chi(B_j)$$
valid for any collection $(B_j)_{j=1}^n$ of measurable sets (here $\chi(A)$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A$).